# Avoiding singularity matrix in regression

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I want to run quantile regression on the following high dimensional code(n=123, p =945) .. but I get an error saying the design matrix is singular and cannot compute. Below is how i extracted the data using the PRIMsrc package.

```
library(PRIMsrc)
data(Real.2)
df<-Real.2
y<-df$y
X<-data.matrix(df[2:946])
library(quantreg)
rq1 = rq(y ~X,tau=1)
```

This seems to be an issue with the data itself so i tried to add some noise to the response using jitter() with the base package, but this didn't solve the issue. Any idea?

Comment: How can you estimate 945 parameters with 123 observations?

Comment: @RuiBarradas It's quite common with genetic data - of course not all covariates are associated and therefore some kind of variable screening must be done to find the non-sparse coefficients.

Comment: @RuiBarradas is correct. you cannot fit a conventional regression model. There simply isn't enough degrees of freedom. The non-sparse coefficients you are talking about, thats either ridge or lasso

Comment: you need to use rq.fit.lasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many variables to fit with too little observations. It's not quite possible to get an estimate for all of them. In your case, I suggest you try a lasso:

```
library(PRIMsrc)
data(Real.2)
df<-Real.2
y<-df$y
X<-data.matrix(df[2:946])
library(quantreg)
rq1 = rq.fit.lasso(y=y,x=X,tau=0.5)
```

The coefficients can be found under:

```
rq1$coefficients
```

For predictions etc, this should work ok. For inferences based on the coefficients etc, you might need to give it more thought